# Do you clean up the unused scripts in a Visual Studio MVC project?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, visual-studio-2008

I am finalizing a MVC project and have switched to using Google's CDN for jQuery. After doing that, do you delete out the unused .JS files from the scripts folder?

Comment: why do you want google to be able to monitor all the traffic on your site? unless youre already using analytics...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I personally keep them around, so that if I go back to development and want to reference the scripts locally again, I can do that without getting them in place all over again.

Answer (score 4):

Did you leave all the extra default plumbing visual studios adds for the controllers, views, models that no one ever uses?   (i sure hope you answered no)

that should answer this question to.  no sense having stuff your not using laying around.

Answer (score 1):

I'd leave them around whilst developing (just in case...) but once finished and sure I won't need them I'd delete them. It's only going to cause confusion for other developers if they assume you are referencing them locally as they've seen them in the Scripts folder. If you are *really* squeamish about deleting them, I guess you could always exclude them from the project - but really I see no point so delete 'em!